# draw image to canvas proplem

Tags: javascript, oop, html5-canvas

its very confused i`m designing a 2d game and i use this code to draw images to canvas the alert method return background.x = 0 ! but when i change x to z or any letter its return the number 400 i ! why background.x always equal to zero ???

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('game'); 
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function loadResources(){
background = new Image();
background.src = "11.jpg";
background.width = 128;
background.height = 128;
background.x = 400;
background.y = 450;

}

function drawimage(){
alert(background.x);
context.drawImage(background,background.x,background.y,background.width,background.height);

}

function gameLoop() {
drawimage();
}


loadResources();
setInterval(gameLoop, 1000/60);
```

Comment: HTML DOM Image Object doesn't contain any x or y properties : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp. So basically background.x doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other objects, you are actually not able to set properties of an Image object that do not belong to it. As you've seen, when you try to access them after setting them, the properties will not be available.  You can slightly rework your code as follows to get the behavior you're looking for:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('game'); 
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var resources = {};

function loadResources(){
    resources.background = new Image();
    resources.background.src = "11.jpg";
    resources.background.width = 128;
    resources.background.height = 128;
    resources.backgroundx = 400;
    resources.backgroundy = 450;
}

function drawimage(){
    console.log(resources.backgroundx);
    context.drawImage(resources.background,resources.backgroundx,resources.backgroundy,resources.background.width,resources.background.height);
}

function gameLoop() {
    drawimage();
}


loadResources();
setInterval(gameLoop, 1000/60);
```